# Apply on pandas' categorical Series with None

Tags: python, pandas

The following code

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'animals': 'kot pies lis kot'.split() + [None]
}, dtype='category')

df.animals.apply(len)
```

returns `4` for None:

```
0    3
1    4
2    3
3    3
4    4
Name: animals, dtype: int64
```

Is it a bug in pandas or a "feature"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems bug, but better is use [`str.len`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.len.html) for correctly handling `NaN`s and `None`s:

```
print (df.animals.str.len())
0    3.0
1    4.0
2    3.0
3    3.0
4    NaN
Name: animals, dtype: float64
```

For non categorical `apply(len)` return error:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'animals': 'kot pies lis kot'.split() + [None]
})

print (df.animals.apply(len))
```

> TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()

But `str.len` working nice:

```
print (df.animals.str.len())
0    3.0
1    4.0
2    3.0
3    3.0
4    NaN
Name: animals, dtype: float64
```